# jquery sort list when dragging icon only, not the text part

Tags: jquery, sorting, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if there is a way to drag to sort a list only when dragging on the icon only, not the text.

Using the example here https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ 
I would like to only the "sort" icon to be draggable, while the text "Item #" is not draggable.  While the "sort" icon is being dragged, I would like to see "Item #" also being dragged and not just the icon so it is clear which item is being dragged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Handle

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    handle: ".handle" //sort icon
});
```

Comment: Oh man.  Thanks so much.  I can't believe I didn't see this in the documentation.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)